# Добавление параметра disable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Привет.
Возникла такая проблема.
У меня есть 2 проверки "if":
первая должна проверять `if ((audio.MicL) == "mute")`
вторая - `if ((audio.MicL) != "mute")`

```
if ((audio.MicL) == "mute"); {
            $(document.getElementById("muteMicL").checked = false);  
            $("#slider-vertical_micl").slider( "option", "disabled", true );
        }

 if ((audio.MicL) != "mute"); {
            $(document.getElementById("muteMicL").checked = true);
            $("#slider-vertical_micl").slider("option", "disabled", false);
        }
```

После того как хотя бы 1 раз изменился параметр `"audio.MicL"`, слайдер больше не блокируется, а галочка в `"checkbox"` не появляется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы на твоем месте написал вместо `$(document.getElementById("muteMicL").checked = false);` -> `$("#muteMicL").removeAttr('checked');`

а вместо `$(document.getElementById("muteMicL").checked = true);` -> `$("#muteMicL").prop('checked','true'); или $("#muteMicL").attr('checked','true');`

Comment: Вопрос еще: почему не работает с "else"?

Comment: А весь код можно, так сложно сказать.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SsbpMmkK

Comment: А где там условие "else"?

Comment: я до этого добавлял условие else, вместо второго if

Comment: Есть ошибки, замени это: 

    if ((audio.MicL) == "mute"); {
                $(document.getElementById("muteMicL").checked = false);
                $("#slider-vertical_micl").slider("option", "disabled", true);
            }
 
            if ((audio.MicL) != "mute"); {
                $(document.getElementById("muteMicL").checked = true);
                $("#slider-vertical_micl").slider("option", "disabled", false);
            }

Comment: на
 
    if (audio.MicL == "mute") {
                $(document.getElementById("muteMicL").checked = false);
                $("#slider-vertical_micl").slider("option", "disabled", true);
            } else {
                $(document.getElementById("muteMicL").checked = true);
                $("#slider-vertical_micl").slider("option", "disabled", false);
            }


у вас перед { стояло ;